# Terminal no longer appears in Geany after installing 14.04

Tags: 14.04, geany

I've upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and now for some odd reason i no longer get the terminal in the bottom of Geany. I have searched the web and i also went through the preferences, but cannot find the solution to the problem.

libvte-2.90-9 is already installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I have found the answer by installing an older version of libvte. That is most likely due to Geany still using GTK2 rather than GTK3. So the solution of this problem under Ubuntu 14.04 is:

```
sudo apt-get install libvte9
```

P.S. This is still the solution under 16.04

Comment: I don't know what VTE is, but shouldn't I be concerned about installing an obsolete version of a library that was apparently installed by default with my OS? Will this overwrite the version of libvte I already have?

Comment: @JackM, What Ubuntu version do you use? I think they've resolved the issue and now the terminal appears by default.

Comment: On latest ubuntus you should install `libvte-2.91-0`